# Dumping only certain part of table with pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I want to dump a table of a PostgreSQL database (on Heroku) but want to only get *the rows of the table matching certain a criteria*, e.g.

`created_at > "2016-01-01"`.

Is that even possible using the `pg_dump` utility?

Comment: Use `copy` (or `\copy`). You can specify a SELECT statement for that.

Comment: But is this scriptable? Like calling `get_truncated_table.rb > table.dump` on the shell and getting the output into the file?

Comment: Sure, instead of running `pg_dump` you run `psql` with the appropriate SQL statements. If you _also_ want the table definition, then you need to first run `pg_dump  --schema-only` and then dump the data using `psql`

Comment: Thanks a lot @a_horse_with_no_name! I will try to prepare a proper answer in case you don't want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`pg_dump` cannot do that. You can use `COPY` to extract data from a single table with a condition:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM tab WHERE created_at > '2016-01-01') TO '/data/dumpfile';
```