# how to take backup of specific data from a table and dump it in existing database and table?

Tags: postgresql, restore, pg-dump

I am working on a PostgreSQL database and I need to take a backup of specific data from a table and restore it into the same or a different database. I am looking for a way to accomplish this task using command-line tools or scripts.

I have tried using the pg_dump and pg_restore command-line utilities, but they seem to only allow for backing up and restoring an entire database or table, rather than specific data within a table.

Is there a way to take a backup of specific data from a table in PostgreSQL and restore it into a database? If so, could you provide an example of the command or script that would accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36310279/6464308) question.

Comment: thanks @LaurenzAlbe copy function in postgresql seems useful